# Finding the value of a point on a straight line

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, geometric-construction

[image]

Hi i'm really bad in math , i need your help for that, i'm looking for a way to find the star point value lining on a straight line as on the picture posted .

Comment: We need more details. What is that black line?

Comment: Do we? Isn't that simple an intersection of $x/0.29+y/0.52=1$ with $y=x$ (by symmetry)? Plug and solve

Comment: Is the red line in the first quadrant the $45^\circ$ line?  It looks like you just want the intersection of that line with the segment joining $(0,.52)$ to $(.29,0)$ and all these curves are irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, so the black line satisfies the equation $y= -\frac {59}{29}x+ 0.59$ so the point is $(x, -\frac {59}{29}x + 0.59)$ for some $x$.  The gray line *looks* like it satisfies the equation $y=x$, so it looks like we should have $x =  -\frac {59}{29}x + 0.59$ or $x=\frac{0.59}{1+\frac {59}{29}}$ the point is $(\frac{0.59}{1+\frac {59}{29}},\frac{0.59}{1+\frac {59}{29}})$.  But that's only what it *looks* like.  We need some way to know what the gray line *is*. And it looks like the *whole* picture would give us information but right now we don't have enough.

Comment: If we had the full picture it *maybe* by the intersections of the gazillions of circles could tell us what the gray line is. As it is we can only *guess* that the gray line is $y=x$.

Comment: Where'd the question come from? Is that the whole picture?

Answer (score 1):

The black line segment appears to be the part of the line 
$$  y = 0.52 + \frac{-0.52}{0.29}x  $$
in the first quadrant.  The gray line intersecting it at the star appears to be part of the line $y = x$.

If appearances are not deceiving, then the two coordinates of the star are the same and we can get one of them by substituting the one linear equation into the other:
$$  x = 0.52 + \frac{-0.52}{0.29}x  $$
and solving for the surviving variable \begin{align*}
x &= 0.52 + \frac{-0.52}{0.29}x  \\
x - \frac{-0.52}{0.29}x &= 0.52  \\
x\left(1 - \frac{-0.52}{0.29}\right) &= 0.52  \\
x &= \frac{0.52}{1 - \frac{-0.52}{0.29}}  \cdot  \frac{0.29}{0.29}  \\
x &= \frac{0.52 \cdot 0.29}{0.29 + 0.52}  \\
x &= 0.186{\dots}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

So the coordinates of the star appear to be $(0.186{\dots}, 0.186{\dots})$.

Comment: "The gray line intersecting it at the star appears to be part of the line y=x."  *APPEARS* to be.  We have no way of knowing that it *is*.

Comment: @fleablood : I see no correction in your comment.